# Public key encryption in objective-C/iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, soap, rsa

I have a .net desktop application which calls SOAP services. The SOAP request sends some data encrypted with .net 'RSACryptoServiceProvider' library. I have the public key for encryption.

I am trying to port this application into iPhone, which requires me to do the public key encryption in objective-c/iPhone.

Can anyone please point me to some library that I can use for public key encryption?

I am trying openSSL, but I can't find enough documents on how to encrypt data with existing public key.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CommonCrypto framework.

See also [The Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157) and the [CryptoExercise Sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html)